When should I use the substitution $u=\frac{1-x}{x+1}$?
I see people use the substitution $u= \frac{1-x}{x+1}$ in integrals but I have no idea when to use it. I can see that this function $f(x)=\frac{1-x}{x+1}$ has an interesting property when trying to find the inverse function i.e $f(f(x))=x$.
I want to know when one should use this substitution  and why, for example when one sees $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ the first thing that come to the mind is  $x= \sin u $ because $1-\sin^2 u =\cos^2 u$, when one see $1+x^2$ the first thing that come to the mind is $x= \tan u $ because $1+\tan^2 u = sec^2 u$. in these examples the superstition is used to make use of some formula that will simplify the equation in the integral but I don't see the reason why people use $u=\frac{1-x}{x+1}$ or $u^2=\frac{1-x}{x+1}$. Another question is: Does this substitution have a name ?

"I want to know when one should use this substitution" $\int_0^1f\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)dx$ seems a good candidate. I don't know of it does have a name.

See if this answers your question.

Note that this transformation is a specific case of the more general transformation $x = \frac{at , + , b}{t , + , 1},$ which is used in Section 5 of this MSE answer for a nontrivial choice of the constants $a$ and $b,$ and one purpose of this transformation is explained in Section 4 of that answer.

We call substitutions like these “Linear fractional transformations”: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearFractionalTransformation.html

As a fun exercise, you can use the substitution $u = \frac{1-x}{1+x}$ on integrals of the form $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan x}{bx^{2}-bx+x+1}dx$ where they are Riemann integrable for $-\infty<b<3+2\sqrt{2}$.

Yes actually it comes from a specific source :
Namely :
First
Having $x\to \sqrt{1-x^2}$, you want to get rid of the square root because it isn't convenient for integration. And a way to make it disappears is setting $x=\cos(\theta)$ because $1-\cos(\theta)^2=\sin(\theta)^2$, take the square root and then you have the $|\sin(\theta)|$, no more square root !
So $$\int_0^1  \sqrt{1-x^2}= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)d\theta$$
Secondly
You ends up with a trigonometric integral.
For trigonometric integrand you can use often the following substitution :
$$ x= \tan(\theta/2) $$ with $\theta$ a new variable.
Why ?
Because it allows to get from trigonometric to polynomial (without roots) $$ \cos(\theta) =\dfrac{1-x^2}{1+x^2} \ \ \text{See how it it close to your problem}$$
and
$$ \sin(\theta)= \dfrac{2x}{1+x^2} $$
and also (!)
$$ \tan(\theta)= \dfrac{2x}{1-x^2} $$
It allow you to turn any trigonometric integral into polynomial (according you get rid of the roots if more complex roots occur)
Is it better for you ?
